# taking the values in checkBox and insert it to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox

I am trying to create a php function where user can check on a list of people to send them messages, however it seems like something wrong with getting the values in an array and inserting them into database one by one.
here's by code:

```
$message=$_POST['body'];
  $x = $_POST['authors'];
  if( isset($x  ) && is_array($x)) {
      $fulexp = implode(",", $x);
foreach ($x as $item) 
   {
    $fulexp = implode(",", $x);
    $var = intval($item);    
    mysql_select_db('mydb');
    $re =  mysql_query("INSERT INTO member_message_member (member_id1, member_id2,conference_id, message)
                    VALUES (6, $var, 1,  $message)");

     if (!$re) {echo "ya a7maaaad";}
   }   
}
else {echo "enta mush msyttar";}
mysql_close($con);
}
```

when i submit the message, nothing inserted into database. anyone can help?

Comment: Of course, before you posted on SO, you did basic debugging like checking which lines of code actually run, printing out the contents of the SQL query after variables inserted, and printing out any MySql error messages that occurred.  What were those results?

Comment: @mellamokb the result is that the sql query didn't run, i guess i stated this in the question (nothing inserted in the database)

Comment: SQL Queries dont just "not run" if you've validated that the PHP is indeed hitting that line of code.  They either run successfully or report some sort of error message.  Since you didn't get the result you expected (a row added to `member_message_member`), it must be generating an error message of some sort.  Perhaps, something to do with `$message` being a string value but not wrapped in single quotes?

Comment: As mellamokb said. What was the specific MySQL error returned? Was there an error returned? Are you connected to the right database? What was your due diligence?

Comment: the message printed in this line if (!$re) {echo "ya a7maaaad";}, which means that no result for query.

Comment: In your debug environment, get the error messages printed out.  One simple method is `mysql_query(...) or die mysql_error();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with

```
mysql_select_db('mydb', $link);
```

where, $link should be defined as below:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
```

Also, the line

```
$fulexp = implode(",", $x);
```

in for loop is redundant may be.